# Unstable behavior of OneClassSVM by changing 'nu'

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, outliers, anomaly-detection

In the example above, I'm using my dataset to identify outliers. After making slight changes to the `nu` parameter, there is a huge difference in the number of anomalies identified.

[image: One class SVM]

Could this be just a particularity of the dataset? Or a bug in scikit-learn?

P.S. Unfortunately I cannot share the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

If you decrease the value of the `tol` parameter of the `OneClassSVM` the result is better although not completely as expected for low values of nu.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(100, 1)
nus = np.geomspace(0.0001, 0.5, num=100)

outlier_fraction = np.zeros(len(nus))
for i, nu in enumerate(nus):
    outlier_fraction[i] = (OneClassSVM(nu=nu, tol=1e-12).fit_predict(X) == -1).mean()

plt.plot(nus, outlier_fraction)
plt.xlabel('nu')
plt.ylabel('Outlier fraction')
plt.show()
```

[image: nu_small_tol]

With the default `tol` you obtain the following
[image]

Comment: could you add the plot to the post?

Comment: I added the plot returned by the code snipped and I also added the plot obtained with the default `tol`

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: not an answer. Offering a MCVE.

I also recently came across this. I would like to understand the inflection point at the low values

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

X = np.random.rand(100, 1)

nu = np.geomspace(0.0001, 1, num=100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'nu': nu})

for i in range(0, len(X)):
    df.loc[i, 'anom_count'] = (OneClassSVM(nu=df.loc[i, 'nu']).fit_predict(X) == -1).sum()

df.set_index('nu').plot();
```

[image]

```
df.set_index('nu').plot(xlim=(0, 0.2));
```

[image]

```
df.anom_count.min() # 3
df.anom_count.idxmin() # 62
df.loc[df.anom_count.idxmin(), 'nu'] # 0.031
```